# American English date format (ММ/dd/yyyy) in the "Input.Date" in AdaptiveCard desktop Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm notice what in the desktop version MS Teams calendar in adaptive card after latest updates become in American English date format (MM/dd/yyyy):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4R0C.png

But earlier date was at Russian format (dd.MMM.yyyy). And in the web version of Teams date in Russian format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRnl9.png

In the both cases adaptive card is same. Is it a bug, or we should change some settings in the Teams Administation site as tenant admins for turning back date Russian format? Thank you.

UPD: Teams cache I'm also cleared and that problem has for all my collegues with Russian language Teams application

Comment: It is also amusing that the US version has Monday as the first day of week and the RU has Sunday, and it should be the other way round, but is this a programming question?

Comment: That fact strange for me too, about  first day of week.. I don't remember what day was a first earlier in the desktop version Teams, but I think it was a monday

Comment: @СергейСимонов - We are checking this internally. We will let you know.

Comment: @СергейСимонов - Please change language settings in MS Teams App settings and confirm if that helps in changing back to Russian format?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I'm changed Teams language setting on Russian, but calendar format is still on American English: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5txs.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPOwH.png

Comment: @СергейСимонов - We are checking this internally. We will let you know.

Comment: @СергейСимонов - The format change issue has been fixed and the fix will be rolled out publicly soon. and the team is working on the discrepancy in starting day of the week on desktop and web.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Hello! We have now another problem. When user picked date in calendar in the adaptive card and sent it to bot, bot recieved another date, instead which user has sent. This is an example of issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqeOs.png. I'm sent date "08/11/2021" and bot get "2021-08-10" wrong date.

Comment: We already have a bug raised for the date issue. We will let you know once it is fixed.

Comment: @СергейСимонов - Getting previous date issue has been fixed. We have checked and its working fine.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Hello! We are checked this issue too, and it's still here. I've picked 07 Feb 2022 in calendar within adaptive card and in teams bot service was sent 06 Feb 2022. Our Teams Version 1.4.00.32771

Comment: We checked and its working fine. Our Teams version is 1.4.00.35564.

Comment: The fix has reached R4, so these issues should not be happening anymore. Could you please help by checking again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :
The bug is fixed now. Please try to update your Teams version and check. Attaching screenshot below for reference:

Desktop:

[image]

Web :

[image]